# Android Studio can't find installed SDK packages

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-studio, intellij-13

So I installed all my SDK packages using the SDK manager tool.  When I search the path where Android Studio is looking for my SDK content everything shows up correctly.  I can even find the actual package I'm looking for.  However, when I type "import android.support...etc" in my Java class it "Cannot resolve".  I have no idea on what to do. My other packages like android.view.View come up fine so it must be recognizing that I have a SDK folder right?  How can I resolve this besides deleting everything and starting from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the android support library a dependency of the module in question. To do so open up your module's `build.gradle` file and insert the following.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```